# Magento: Updating Product Catalogs faster

Tags: magento

I have written quite a few scripts to update my product catalog based on some or other parameter. In each of them the base logic is something simillar to this...

```
     //Get collection
     $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
     $collection->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('publihser');
     $collection->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'publisher','eq'=>$publisher)));

     // for each product in collection do a individual save
     foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->setSKU($newValue);
    $product->save();   
            }
```

Though this work, each save is a SQL update query and the fact is that having a very large catalog, this is fairly slow.

I was wondering if this could be sped up by doing single save on the collection instead on the product.

Comment: Does this run in the browser or cli?

Comment: try [MAGMI](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki).

Comment: @djdy This is running on CLI.. but can also be run on Web interface.

Comment: @user971401. I will be trying MAGMI, but from what I read, it needs to give SKU id. In my case, it can be any attribute. for example, if attribute publisher and no image, then set image as xyz.jpg.

Comment: @TheVyom - I'm using [Magmi Datapump API](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Magmi_Datapump_API) for both importing and updating my catalog products in Magento. Read on, this is really fast and powerful.

Comment: `publihser` is just a typo, right?

Comment: saving the collection will work but will be slow too check the class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::save().

Comment: @Diglin Tried to do collection->save() but was extremely slow.

Comment: @JürgenThelen Sorry.. the Publihser was a typo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several things you can do to write a much faster update script. I don't know how you are getting some of your variables so you'll need to modify to get it working in your case, but the code below should be much faster than the way you are currently doing it. e.g:

```
// Set indexing to manual before starting updates, otherwise it'll continually get slower as you update
$processes = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessesCollection();
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL));
$processes->walk('save');

// Get Collection
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('publihser')
    ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'publisher','eq'=>$publisher)));


function productUpdateCallback($args){
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $product->setData($args['row']);

    $productId = $product->getId();

    $sku = 'yourSku';

    // Updates a single attribute, much faster than calling a full product save
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')
        ->updateAttributes(array($productId), array('sku' => $sku), 0);
}

// Walk through collection, for large collections this is much faster than using foreach
Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($collection->getSelect(), array('productUpdateCallback'));


// Reindex all
$processes->walk('reindexAll');
// Set indexing back to realtime, if you have it set to manual normally you can comment this line out
$processes->walk('setMode', array(Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_REAL_TIME));
$processes->walk('save');
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasuten. Your answer is full of ideas which I can use to improve the speed.

Comment: I get `Call to a member function getAttributeId() on a non-object in \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Product\Action.php on line 69` when trying to update `category_ids`. Is there no way to modify that "attribute" (it's not really an attribute) this way, or any way faster than `$product->setCategoryIds('1,2,3')->save();`